# Why Number("0") || undefined is equal to undefined and not zero?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a filter with Javascript and sometimes the filter number may be 0 or just an empty string. Something like this:

```
const exampleFromTheBackend = "0"
myFilter: Number(exampleFromTheBackend) || undefined
```

And when receiving 0, I was expecting that the Number library would return 0 and not undefined. Is there any way to keep the zero without having to do something like:

```
myFilter: Number(exampleFromTheBackend) || 0
```

Because I need the undefined for when the filters are not all full.

Comment: that equates to `0 || "test"`, and `0` is [falsey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) so it'll return the other value instead. Maybe [a ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is what you're looking for: `num === "0" || Number(num) ? Number(num) : undefined`. That way it'll return `Number(num)` if `num` evaluates to truthy (any non-zero number) or 0.

Comment: what other values/types do you have?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones is there any workaround?

Comment: What value from the backend should be translated to `undefined`?

Comment: My own approach (until more information is provided) would be something like: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gd0rnq84/), but surely if the value itself is not passed, then the value would *be* undefined, so... I'm confused until Barmar's question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check it by `!isNaN(Number(exampleFromBackend)) && exampleFromBackend !== ""`

Answer (score 0):

fixed with this not much elegant solution

```
myFilter: Number(exampleFromTheBackend) === 0 ? 0 : Number(exampleFromTheBackend) || undefined
```